# Delete row based on formula result in that row

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete the entire row based on the content of a cell in that row.

The cell has a formula, which resolves to either 1 or zero. Should delete row if 1.

The code below deletes every row, regardless of what is in AB.

```vb
Sub Delete()

Dim FoundCell As  AB
Set FoundCell = Worksheets("PM2CORRELATED").Range("AB4:AB1500").Find(what:=1)
Do Until FoundCell Is Nothing
    FoundCell.EntireRow.Delete
    Set FoundCell = Worksheets("PM2CORRELATED").Range("AB4:AB1500").FindNext
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Should be `Dim FoundCell As range`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting rows one by one, you can filter them and delete the results

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()
    
    ' Set target sheet
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PM2CORRELATED")
    
    ' Set target range
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = targetSheet.Range("AA4:AA1500")
    
    ' Filter cells
    targetRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=1
    
    ' Delete the filtered rows
    targetRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(targetRange.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    
    ' Turn off autofilter
    targetSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    If targetSheet.FilterMode = True Then
        targetSheet.ShowAllData
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: And it works like magic!

Thanks So much!

Comment: Remember to mark the answer so others may find it too

Answer (score 0):

You're making a typical rookie mistake here: when you delete something from a list, you need to do it from end back to beginning, not from beginning to the end.

Let me give you an example: you have collection `[1,0,0,1,1,1]` and you want to delete every zero, first you do this from beginning to end:

```
(Pseudo-code)
For index=1 to 6
  if collection[index] = 0
  then collection.remove(index)
next
```

This is what happens with your index and your collection:

```
index = 1, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 2, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 0 => remove the second entry
result after removal : collection = [1,0,1,0,1]
index = 3, collection = [1,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 4, collection = [1,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 5, collection = [1,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 6, collection = [1,0,1,0,1], collection[index] = ERROR: there are no 6 elements anymore
```

You see, when you go from beginning to end, duplicates cause some entries not to be deleted, and you might even get an error.

Now let's do it the other way around:

```
(Again pseudo-code)
from index=6 to 1
  if collection[index] = 0
  then collection.remove(index)
step -1
```

This is what happens with your index and your collection:

```
index = 6, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 5, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 4, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
index = 3, collection = [1,0,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 0 => remove the third entry:
collection = [1,0,1,1,1]
index = 2, collection = [1,0,1,1,1], collection[index] = 0 => remove the second entry:
collection = [1,1,1,1]
index = 1, collection = [1,1,1,1], collection[index] = 1 => do nothing
```

Good luck